# Bootstrap: jQuery TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In the following web site I'm setting up:

http://shfa.designbytricia.com/

I can't seem to use jquery via the "$" short cut. If i go into the debug console and type

```
$('ul.nav');
```

I get "TypeError: undefined is not a function"

However if I type:

```
jQuery('ul.nav');
```

I get what I expect, the ul with the nav class on it.

I can't figure out what is causing this to happen. I'm using chrome, and when I start typing the $ it starts autofilling and gives me the following options $, $$, $x which seems to be the jquery shortcut is working.

Can someone help?

Comment: Have you got some plug-in, component or framework besides jQuery that you are using?

Comment: are you using some cms. Wordpress for example loads jQuery in no conflict mode, which could cause the issue..

Comment: I am using Wordpress. I didn't know it loads it up in no conflict mode. I don't see any javascript in the source putting it into no conflict mode. Is it actually in the jquery source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using wordpress. Wordpress loads jQuery in no conflict mode. It's bundled into the source of jQuery. Now you know.

You write a function like this to remove the no conflict.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
}
```

Then you get the $ short cut back.